# How to compare related count with own column in Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Assume we have an `agents` table with a `quota` column and a many-to-many relationship to `tickets`. With Laravel Eloquent ORM, how can I select only agents having less or equal number of 'tickets' than their 'quota'?

Eager-loading objects must be avoided.

```
class Agent extends Model {

   public function tickets()
   {
      return $this->belongsToMany(Ticket::class, 'agent_tickets')
          ->using(AgentTicket::class);
   }

   public function scopeQuotaReached($query)
   {
      // Does not work. withCount is an aggregate.
      return $query->withCount('tickets')
          ->where('tickets_count', '<=', 'quota');

      // Does not work. Tries to compare against the string "quota".
      return $query->has('tickets', '<=', 'quota');
   }

}
```

Is there a more eloquent (pun intended) way to solve this than using a `DB::raw()` query with joining and grouping and counting manually?

Answer (score 4):

Derived columns like `tickets_count` can only be accessed in the `HAVING` clause.

Since there is no `havingColumn()` method, you'll have to use a raw expression:

```
$query->withCount('tickets')->having('tickets_count', '<=', DB::raw('quota'));
```

Comment: That compares the 'tickets_count' against the "quota" *string* not against the `quota` column value.  Replace `quota` with `abcdef123` and the query still runs fine.

Comment: Hold on...  if we add `->get()` or `->first()` or `->exists()` this works fine. It throws an exception if we add `->count()`. Is this an Eloquent bug?

Comment: This requires a subquery: `Agent::fromSub(Agent::withCount('tickets')->having('tickets_count', '<=', DB::raw('quota')), 'alias')->count()`

Answer (score 0):

At a database level I don't know how to achieve this, but you could do it at a Collection level.

```
// Get users
$agents = Agent::withCount('tickets')->get();
// filter
$good_agents = $agents->filter(function ($agent, $key) {
                   return $agent->tickets_count >= $agent->quota;
               })
               ->all();
```

Of course you can inline it:

```
$good_agents = Agent
    ::withCount('tickets')
    ->get()
    ->filter(function ($agent, $key) {
        return $agent->tickets_count >= $agent->quota;
    })
    ->all();
```

Comment: Accurate, although I do need it to be query scope I can add more clauses to down the pipe. Thanks, I've used a similar approach in another app.